# TypeORM substracts 1 day of date 00:00:00 (probably a Tedious bug)

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, typeorm, tedious

I'm working with a legacy SQL Server dtabase that stores dates NOT in UTC format. I'm trying to insert a `smalldatetime` using TypeORM.

This is what TypeORM executes:

```
INSERT INTO foo(date) VALUES (@0)
-- PARAMS: SELECT * FROM @OutputTable -- PARAMETERS: [{"value":"2020-11-09T23:00:00.000Z","type":"smalldatetime","params":[]}]
```

This should save '2020-11-10 00:00:00' in DB (GMT +1, server also GMT +1) but, for some reason, is saving '2020-11-09 00:00:00'. I think when the result date that TypeORM tries to insert is 00:00:00 it doesn't change the day. I've tried with other timestamps and, as long as it's greater or equal 00:01:00 it works

- Operating System: Windows
- Node.js: v12.16.2
- Typescript: v4.0.3
- TypeORM: v0.2.28

UPDATE:

According to this thread: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3202 it probably has something to do with `tedious` version. Now problem is when I tried to update `mssql 7.0.0-alpha.1` version (in order to update `tedious`) typeorm can't connect:

```
const serverSql: SqlServerConnectionOptions = {
        name: process.env.DB_SQL_DEFAULT_NAME,
        entities: [`${__dirname}/../../schemas/**/*.js`],
        type: 'mssql',
        host: process.env.DB_SQL_DEFAULT_HOST,
        port: Number(process.env.DB_SQL_DEFAULT_PORT),
        username: process.env.DB_SQL_DEFAULT_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_SQL_DEFAULT_PASSWORD,
        requestTimeout: 30000,
        options: {
          connectionIsolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',
          isolation: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',
          enableArithAbort: false
        },
        pool: {
          acquireTimeoutMillis: 30000
        },
        logging: 'all'
      };
      await createConnections([serverSql]);
```

Throws this error: `Connection error: The "config.options.connectionIsolationLevel" property must be of type number. Received type string (READ_UNCOMMITTED)`

Comment: `smalldatetime` has no context of timezones. If you pass it `'2020-11-09T23:00:00.000Z'` it'll be stored as `2020-11-09T23:00`; the timezone information will simply be ignored, it isn't converted to the instance's local timezone.

Comment: But TypeORM converts it to local timezone, so in GMT+1 although it says `2020-11-09T23:00:00.000Z` it inserts `2020-11-10T00:00` (or should, currently it inserts `2020-11-09T00:00`)